# how to avoid dots next to a uitextfield

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextfield

Is that possible to remove the dots which are displayed next to uitextfield when text is larger than the width of the uitextfield.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There is a property lineBreakMode which defines the behaviour when the text to be displayed is larger than the box of the control

```
//UILineBreakMode
//Options for wrapping and truncating text.

typedef enum {
 UILineBreakModeWordWrap = 0,
 UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap,
 UILineBreakModeClip,
 UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation,
 UILineBreakModeTailTruncation,
 UILineBreakModeMiddleTruncation,
} UILineBreakMode;
```

If you do not want any dots you can use **UILineBreakModeClip** which simply cuts the text off at the end. The apple doc  says this:

> Clip the text when the end of the drawing rectangle is reached. This option could result       in a partially rendered character at the end of a string.
>   **Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.**

Although it of course depends on how you want to display the text. Since either way you cannot display all of the text the dots are usually more asthetic than a raw break.

If you require absolutely all of the text to be visible you must either expand the *width* of the field, or the *height* (and use **UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap**), or possibly decrease the font size (as a last resort).

A quick google search on the subject pulled this [How to make UILabel / UITableViewCell to have a dynamic height](http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=410)

Comment: The question asks about UITextField - There is no setLineBreakMode for a UITextField

Comment: Like Ben said, this is useless with UITextField.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you make keyboard visible calling following code

[self.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Then larger text is clipped from left.

you can also hide keyboard [if you use any custom keyboard] using following code

```
// Hide keyboard for Dial Pad, but show blinking cursor
UIView *dummyKeyboardView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
yourTextField.inputView = dummyKeyboardView;
[dummyKeyboardView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but I needed an answer since I was trying to make a very tight instrument panel, so the text size had to be very optimized, and the last few versions of iOS make text needlessly small with `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES` (not sure which version changed this, iOS 9 gets text to fit to the edges, iOS 13 leaves lots of space).
Obviously `lineBreakMode` is useless. What I ended up doing is give a few extra pixels width to the text rectangle:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, -4, 0);
}
```

The above will give an extra 4 pixels on each side for overdrawing, because in my case I had centered text that might sometimes not exactly fit horizontally - adjust the returned rectangle for your needs. But in general, this way you can keep `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO`, and choose a font size "dangerously close" to your limit without getting those dreaded dots. Whether your overdrawing will be cutoff etc is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

I tried lots of ways and finally I came to following solution.

`UITextField` does not have a `lineBreakMode` property so just override following method in `UITextField`:

```
-(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds{

    CGRect rect = bounds;
    rect.size.width = rect.size.width;
    return rect;
}
```

Note: I dont know how, but it works.