# Remove dot from UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I create on application and i required to enter price. client required its own design keyboard so i develop following keyboard. it works perfect . Problem is when the text is larger then `UITextField`'s with then it display dots. I search on google and SO but not found any thing. 
   [how to avoid dots next to a uitextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287312/how-to-avoid-dots-next-to-a-uitextfield)
   [How to remove dots in UITextfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387703/how-to-remove-dots-in-uitextfield)   and other answer but not working in my case. **When I used default keyboard it scroll the text what i input number**

My key board is

[image]

when length is greater then TextFied Width then it display

[image]

My code is

```
     - (IBAction)numberPressed:(id)sender {
         UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
         int number=btn.tag;

         if (number <= 9)
             txtPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",txtPrice.text, number];
         //decimal point
         else if (number == 10) {
             if ([txtPrice.text rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound)
                 txtPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", txtPrice.text];
          }
         //0
         else if (number == 11)
             txtPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0", txtPrice.text];
         //backspace
         else if (number == 12) {
             if ([txtPrice.text length] > 0)
                 txtPrice.text = [txtPrice.text substringToIndex:[txtPrice.text length] - 1];
             else
                 txtPrice.text = @"";
         }
     }


   #pragma mark -
   #pragma mark -TextField Delegate Method

   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
       [self showKeyboard];
       return NO;  // Hide both keyboard and blinking cursor.
   }

   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
   {
       return YES;
   }
```

Comment: Are you using an `UITextField` or a `UILabel`? A `UILabel` will automatically truncate its contents when they get too long.

Comment: What do you want it to display?

Comment: @PartiallyFinite Thanks for replay, I used  UITextField

Comment: @kushyar Thanks for replay,I want to remove dots, just display number.

Comment: Your screenshot of the truncated text looks like a label to me, not a text field. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` is specifically one-line only. So whatever the `UITextField` is big when it reach the end it will display dots.

You need to use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField` for display and editing of `multiline` text.

In Interface Builder add a `UITextView` where you want it and select the "editable" box. It will be `multiline` by default.

I think this will help you. ^_^

Comment: okay, this is the only way to avoid displaying the dots. Use UITextView which support multi-line. Good Luck!!

Comment: @MKAlatrash I wouldn't say it is the only way but I would probably do it this way myself and deal with the multiple lines, but if the user really wanted to stick with a `UITextField` then they would have to go for `kushyar` answer, but sooner all  later they will be in the same position again as it will meet the minimumFontSize again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
self.txtPrice.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0];
self.txtPrice.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.txtPrice.minimumFontSize = 7.0;
```

"adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" is a Boolean value indicating whether the font size should be reduced in order to fit the text string into the text field’s bounding rectangle.

"minimumFontSize" is the size of the smallest permissible font with which to draw the text field’s text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a similar behavior as the calculator or the phone app you have to set the following property to true(YES):

```
textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

You should also set the `minimumFontSize` property to "to prevent the receiver from reducing the font size to the point where it is no longer legible."

Check out the [UITextField Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Comment: I used UITextField not UILabel

Comment: I can understand the downvote for the `lineBreakMode` which `UITextFields` do not have, but you have corrected so I will upvote this for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is (Remove dot and clip text to frame)-

your can remove dot from UITextField calling following code

[self.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

you can also hide default keyboard [if you use any custom keyboard] using following code

// Hide keyboard for Dial Pad, but show blinking cursor
UIView *dummyKeyboardView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
yourTextField.inputView = dummyKeyboardView;
[dummyKeyboardView release];

But I think IlNero's answer is better for you if you want to show all text (does not clip).

Answer (score -4):

What you can do is

```
  txtPrice.text = [txtPrice.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: This won't work as it is getting word wrapped. So when the length reaches a certain length you will get the "3534..." but when you do `txtPrice.text` it will give the full text. -1 for incorrect answer.

Comment: the whole agenda is to remove dots and my code is just removing dots , not the numbers , so i think it is correct...

Comment: No it isn't. Say you have a number "123456789" and in the `UITextField` it shows as "1234567.." the dots appear because the text is to long for the `UITextField` so it is getting word wrapped or character wrapped, but if I did `[myTextField text]` it would return "123456789". So when you do `[txtPrice.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];` it isn't going to do anything as it doesn't know about the "...". This is just what the user will see in the text field because it is word wrapped. So your answer is wrong.

Comment: you are right that 8 and 9 will be trimmed but the question is to just remove dots , so as per the question my answer is right , now if the words are wrapped then developer can do something .

Comment: To remove them you need to be setting the `lineBreakMode` of the object which `UITextField` doesn't have, so you can't. The only way that it comes close to being able to do it is using `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and setting `minimumFontSize` to something that isn't a silly font size. I also think you have misunderstood the question, the user hasn't entered the dots this has occurred because of word wrapping and when it comes to word wrapping your answer is completely wrong. So sorry no you are wrong as per the question.